# Core Data Memory Leaks

Tags: iphone, ios, memory, core-data

I began testing my app in Instruments to clean up any memory leaks. I've been able to clear up all the memory leaks except those related to Core Data. Instruments always points me to this section of code:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
    // Handle the error
}
```

I declare the managedObjectContext in my header file with the following code:

```
@interface UpperBody : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

IBOutlet UITableView *upperTable;
NSMutableArray *exercises;
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *exercises;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

I release the managedObjectContext in the (void)dealloc section. Here is the full section of code using the managedObjectContext:

```
- (void)loadExercises {

if (managedObjectContext == nil) {
    managedObjectContext = [(iFitAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
}

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Exercises" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"category == 1"];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"exerciseName" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
[sortDescriptor release];
[sortDescriptors release];

NSError *error = nil;
NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
    // Handle the error
}

[self setExercises:mutableFetchResults];
// [exercises addObject:@"Add Exercise"];
NSLog(@"Count of exercises %i", exercises.count);
[mutableFetchResults release];
[request release];
[self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Any advise on what might be causing the leaks would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you release `exercises` in your `dealloc` method?

Comment: Yea, I release exercises in my dealloc method. =/ I'm not sure why Instruments points to the NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults though. I release managedObjectContext, results, and mutableFetchRequests.

Comment: Instruments points to where the leaked object is allocated, not where it is leaked.

Comment: Yea, I understand that instruments points to where the leaked object is allocated. I'm trying to figure out where I go wrong in releasing it.

Comment: Have you tried Build and Analyze? It can find potential leaks...

Comment: Yea, Thanks for the tip! I am playing with Build and Analyze now, but I haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kThere was probably a leak in the code I had above. I got around declaring an NSManagedObjectContext by just using a pointer to one whenever needed. Here is a sample of the code:

```
iFitAppDelegate *appDelegate = (iFitAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
```

This fixed my leak, so it must have had to do with how I was allocated and releasing the NSManagedObjectContext. Thank you for the pointers, @albertamg!